# I'm trying to remove the text which is length less than equal to 4 from the input given. I'm using EasyOcr and the bounding box concept

Tags: python, string, list, data-structures, bounding-box

```
bounds = reader.readtext(np.array(images[0]), min_size=0, slope_ths=0.2, ycenter_ths=0.7, height_ths=0.6, width_ths=0.8,decoder='beamsearch', beamWidth=10)
print(bounds)
```

The output is

```
Output:

[([[1002, 126], [1210, 126], [1210, 222], [1002, 222]], 'uz5', 0.048652395606040955), ([[177, 179], [349, 179], [349, 241], [177, 241]], 'OIZI', 0.7936368584632874), ([[180, 236], [422, 236], [422, 268], [180, 268]], 'Oki Electric Industry Co', 0.4165174067020416), [[180, 236], [422, 236], [422, 268], [180, 268]], 'Industry Co', 0.4165174067020416)]
```

#########

```
print(bounds[0][1])
```

gives output

```
uz5
```

It's giving the first text from the output.

We need to remove the text in the total output with length less than equal to 4.

Expected Output:

```
([[180, 236], [422, 236], [422, 268], [180, 268]], 'Oki Electric Industry Co', 0.4165174067020416), [180, 236], [422, 236], [422, 268], [180, 268]], 'Industry Co', 0.4165174067020416)]
```

Comment: use https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: Can you please write the code?

Comment: read the doc of `filter` and write a small predicate lambda function